# C# ReadLine conversion problems

Tags: c#

I'm a novice to C# and am working on text formatting. I moved off of the lesson plan a bit to format a user-inputted phone number. Although the program compiles and runs, it will crash when inputting something.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Strings
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           int PhoneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

           string myString = string.Format("Phone Number: {0:(###) ###-####}", PhoneNumber);

           Console.WriteLine(myString);
           Console.ReadLine();
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the maximum value for `int` (`Int32`) is 2147483647, which is probably less than the phone number you're entering, causing it to crash with `OverflowException`.

Change `int` to `long`:

```
long PhoneNumber = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

string myString = string.Format("Phone Number: {0:(###) ###-####}", PhoneNumber);

Console.WriteLine(myString);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But I suggest reading and keeping the phone number in an `string` since an integer doesn't really make sense as the data type.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The thing is: I initially tried using a string for this, but it wouldn't make use of the formatting. I'm assuming that the type of format only excepts integers?